# why aluminium reflect less light than matte white paint?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

I'm reading the book: automating hydroponics, from Cerreto Rossouw.

He wrote, p46, *"you shouldn't use aluminium foil because it's quite poor at reflecting light (...) A practical alternative (...) matte white paint, wich is 75-80 percent reflective"*

well, I wonder why aluminium foil is poor at reflecting the light in comparaison of matte white paint. Is it the same for an aluminium mirror ?

Comment: the paint scatters the light so it gets spread nicely around the room.

Comment: I think that the author means that matte white paint may be better as a diffuse reflector of light, which is the property of interest for this hydroponics application. A flat aluminum plate or foil is of course a better specular reflector of light than matte white paint surface is.

Comment: your comments make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is untrue - aluminium reflects around 90% of the incident light.

The difference between aluminium and white paper is that aluminium is glossy and  acts as a mirror. Therewith is "shows" the darker objects in the surrounding which may appear as being darker.